# Box surrounding each digit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to learn more about web programming and html. I have this countdown that I'm trying to style a bit but I'm having difficulty getting what I want.

http://jsfiddle.net/aby3M/

```
.countHeader {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 20;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    white-space: pre;
}
.countLook {
    font-size: 50px;
    z-index: 20;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
    white-space: pre;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                 0px -2px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    border: 10px #f1f1f1;
}

<body>
    <p class="countHeader">        Days                        Hours                       Minutes                     Seconds</p>
    <div id="countdown" class="countLook"></div> 
</body>

function updateWCTime() {
    now = new Date();
    kickoff = Date.parse("November 17, 2013 23:00:00");
    diff = kickoff - now;

    days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    dday1 = Math.floor(days / 10);
    dday2 = days % 10;
    hr = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
    dhr1 = Math.floor(hr / 10);
    dhr2 = hr % 10;
    min = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
    dmin1 = Math.floor(min / 10);
    dmin2 = min % 10;
    sec = Math.floor(diff / (1000)) % 60;
    dsec1 = Math.floor(sec / 10);
    dsec2 = sec %10;


    document.getElementById("countdown")
        .innerHTML =
        ' ' + dday1 + " " + dday2  +'  :  ' + dhr1 + " " + dhr2 + '  :  ' + dmin1 + " " + dmin2 + '  :  ' + dsec1 + " " + dsec2;          
}
setInterval(updateWCTime, 1000);
```

The fiddle shows the basic countdown layout I have. I don't know if its because of the way I have it set up, but I can't figure out how to center a box on each digit. I'm trying to get a box to encase each number similar to http://flipclockjs.com/ but without any of the animations. I just need the background box around each digit. I was trying to do it with just css but maybe there's more to this than I understand. Any help?

Comment: You want a box around each digit? Than you have to place each digit in its own element. The border you have around the countdown now doesn't show because you missed a parameter for the border. It should be something like `border: 10px solid #fefefe;`.

Comment: if you're lazy you could just use a carefully crafted background image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add spans to your digits in the inner HTML. I didnt do them all cause im sure you get the point. Then just use CSS to style them

```
document.getElementById("countdown")
            .innerHTML =
            '<span class="digit"> ' + dday1 + ' </span> <span class="digit"> ' + dday2  +' </span> :  ' + dhr1 + " " + dhr2 + '  :  ' + dmin1 + " " + dmin2 + '  :  ' + dsec1 + " " + dsec2;          
    }
```

Then just style the spans with CSS. I added a nice ugly styling for you to see.

```
.digit{
    background-color:red;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

Demo on first two digits : http://jsfiddle.net/aby3M/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add  tag to every text when adding to .innerHtml then style that span

```
document.getElementById("countdown")
        .innerHTML =
        ' <span>' + dday1 + "</span> <span>" + dday2  +'</span>  : <span>' + dhr1 + "</span> <span> " + dhr2 + '</span>  : <span>' + dmin1 + "</span> <span> " + dmin2 + '</span>  : <span>' + dsec1 + " </span> <span>" + dsec2;    


IN css


.countLook span {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```